# Cannot run an Xamarin UWP app in debug mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to run my Xamarin UWP app in debug mode but if fails to open.  The error code is

[image]

Output window errors

The thread 0x6dfc has exited with code 3221225595 (0xc000007b).
The thread 0x3344 has exited with code 3221225595 (0xc000007b).
The program '[35788] SheepsheadTheGame.UWP.exe' has exited with code 3221225595 (0xc000007b).

I was able to run the app in debug mode and then it just stop working.  All my nuget packages are up to date.  I have searched the web and tried various solutions other people have had success fixing this issue.  I have not been successful.

I have found two lines in the build output window that may be causing the issue.

6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0028: Found native library 'C:\Users\druch\Documents\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\ilc\in\Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll' with unexpected CPU architecture 'amd64', while the current build target architecture is set to 'x86'. Your application may fail to launch. Please make sure to build your application with the matching CPU architecture.

6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.11-rel-30601-02\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0028: Found native library
'C:\Users\druch\Documents\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\ilc\in\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ServiceInterop.dll' with unexpected CPU architecture 'amd64', while the current build target architecture is set to 'x86'. Your application may fail to launch. Please make sure to build your application with the matching CPU architecture.

Could this be the cause of my issue?  If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: it looks the referred dll miss match current project's build target architecture, have you tried to set your project's  build target architecture as x64?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rebuilding my app (not fun).  The UWP app started working again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).